# Want to execute TestPlan in JMeter having listener and also generate report as the same time

Tags: jmeter

I am working on performance testing and I want to generate HTML report and also see the execute in listener as well at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

You are not following [JMeter Best Practices](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html)

**Never Ever Run Performance Tests in GUI Mode**

- Use CLI mode: jmeter -n -t test.jmx -l test.jtl
- Use as few Listeners as possible; if using the -l flag as above they can all be deleted or disabled.
- Don't use "View Results Tree" or "View Results in Table" listeners during the load test, use them only during scripting phase to debug your scripts.
- Rather than using lots of similar samplers, use the same sampler in a loop, and use variables (CSV Data Set) to vary the sample. [The Include Controller does not help here, as it adds all the test elements in the file to the test plan.]
- Don't use functional mode
- Use CSV output rather than XML
- Only save the data that you need
- Use as few Assertions as possible
- Use the most performing scripting language (see JSR223 section)

**To run Performance Tests and generate report after run use following command at once:**

```
jmeter -n -t yourjmxfile.jmx -l result.jtl -e -o /folder
```

Comment: Thanks.. you are right, we should not execute load test on GUI mode but I was getting some hanging issue from application server on load test and due to command line execution I was unable to find the problem so that's why I decided to execute load test on GUI mode and found the issues after time of execution... (READ my second comment)

Comment: Also, I found a workaround

- Prepare JMeter script
- Add View Result Tree (only to check the load status)
- Store the load testing response in .cvs file by putting the path of cvs in View Result Tree.
- When jmeter finished its job then generation from an existing sample CSV log file using following command

`jmeter -g <log file> -o <Path to output folder>`

Comment: Yes you can do that only after test is completed and you have the result file. In question we want to run the test and create the report at once. Use jmeter -n -t yourjmxfile.jmx -l result.jtl -e -o /folder